# Why is Capistrano using /u/apps/ in the current_path, even though I've set :deploy_to

Tags: capistrano

For some reason Capistrano is failing on just about every operation, because it seems to think my `current_path` should be in `/u/apps/`.  I've set all the variables that (AFAIK) should be set, and eliminated all other similar default paths, but this one persists.

Here are the values returned by relevant variables:

```
current_dir: current
releases_path: /var/www/vhosts/dev.www.example.com/html/releases
shared_path: /var/www/vhosts/dev.www.example.com/html/shared
current_path: /u/apps/www.example.com/current
```

I'm setting `:deploy_to`, so shouldn't `current_path` be computed based on that!?

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/dev.www.example.com/"
```

Comment: Another potential cause of this is if the current_path is read before deploy_to. For example, I had a set :sidekiq_pid, "#{current_path}/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid" being invoked before deploy_to which was in a production.rb file, thus causing it to default to /u/apps.

Comment: The above comment by @JohnMerlino was the answer for me. Easiest solution, easiest 'mistake' to make in your code. Occam's shaver says this is the answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kind of kludgey solution is just to manually

```
set :current_path, ""
```

The [better solution, which can be found explained in this e-mail thread by Jamis Buck himself](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/capistrano/-fCIVRLX8Kc), is to use lazy evaluation when you set another variable that depends on `current_path`.  In my case, I had a setting something like this

```
set :some_path_var, "#{current_path}/some/path/"
```

that I had to change to something like this:

```
set(:some_path_var) { "#{current_path}/some/path/" }
```

By passing in a block, the :some_path_var was not immediately evaluated, and did not force `current_path` to be evaluated based on a default value for `:deploy_to`

Answer (score 2):

So I had this issue as well and I found that this was the best solution.

Add this to your `config/deploy.rb`

```
  desc "Make sure the symlink will be from the right directory"
  task :change_correct_dir, roles: :web do
    set :current_path, File.join(deploy_to, current_dir)
  end
  before "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:change_correct_dir"
```

I got the idea from looking at the source of the capistrano gem and finding

`_cset(:current_path)      { File.join(deploy_to, current_dir)`
in

`lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb`

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you don't specify a task in your cap command.

```
cap deploy:setup
```

Will attempt to set up Capistrano in /u/apps

```
cap production deploy:setup
```

Will set up Capistrano in the directory specified in :deploy_to.

Comment: This is only true if the multistage plugin is loaded.