# Capistrano current_path set to /u/app for some commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I've set the `deploy_to` variable to the necessary path, but Capistrano runs a single task in the `u/app/` directory.

Here is the task that is run

```
executing "cat /u/apps/application/current/REVISION"
```

That is how variables are set

```
set :application, "application"
set :deploy_to, "normal_path/#{application}"
```

Part of the log where it happens is here:

```
  * executing "cat /normal_path/applicaiton/TOUCH_ASSETS | while read asset; do touch -cm -- \"$asset\"; done && rm -f -- /normal/TOUCH_ASSETS"
servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
[1.1.1.1] executing command
command finished in 992ms
* executing "cat /u/apps/application/current/REVISION"
servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
[1.1.1.1] executing command
command finished in 427ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /normal_path/applicaiton/releases/20130610233146; true"
servers: ["1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.2"]
[1.1.1.1] executing command
[1.1.1.1] executing command
command finished in 486ms
failed: "sh -c 'cat /u/apps/application/current/REVISION'" on 1.1.1.1
```

Why does Capistrano use the wrong path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Capistrano using /u/apps/ in the current\_path, even though I've set :deploy\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357396/why-is-capistrano-using-u-apps-in-the-current-path-even-though-ive-set-depl)

Comment: @Deefour
I've tried to apply that solution, but it didn't work for me.